# .htaccess file not works in LAMP

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

This is my .htaccess file. I am used Codeigniter Framework for my project.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /project_name/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Where is my mistake here? But It Works in xampp.

Comment: do you mean the code isn't working? or is it giving you 500 error?

Comment: Showing  this  error message when I click another link without index.php :   Not Found

The requested URL /new_notificamos/admin/cetagory was not found on this server.

Comment: Yah.. this file already existed in project and it  controller .. admin is controller.. when I write in url new_notif/index.php/admin/cetagory it works..

Comment: Does it recognize your .htaccessf file at all? If you put some random text in your .htaccess file does it give you an internel server error?

Comment: well, your above .htaccess code is correct. May be providing more information will help us to understand your problem.

Comment: also keep checking apache access_log, it will tell you what URL is actually being called.

Comment: I am little bit unsure that  random text in my .htaccess about it.. xampp works properly this htaccess file.. problem occurred only lamp server..

Comment: The reason I said to put random text in the file is so see if the server is reading the file. If it is you will get an error. OR you can remove `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` from the .htaccess file and it should also error if its not enabled. I bet you have not enabled anything on this server.

Comment: where I can find out this access_log file?

Comment: when I remove <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> it showing same error .. "The requested URL was not found on this server."@Jack

Comment: That tells me .htaccess is probably not enabled. You should get an internal server error, so it's not reading the .htaccess file. Follow my instructions below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your terminal
Run this following code:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

go down and change:

```
AllowOverride All
```

look like:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then restart apache2.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and then .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't just move from one server to another and not make sure your prerequistes are there. These things are not on by default on most systems. You also have not given any specifics about your setup or even your document root.

So going off that it's an Ubuntu server and apache2, you need to do these things.

First thing you need to do if this is a new LAMP install is make sure rewrite is on.

Run this command to enable mod_rewrite.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then you need to make sure you allow .htaccess in your document root.

edit

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

In this file search for this

```
 AllowOverride None
```

and change it to

```
AllowOverride All
```

Then restart apache2.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

EDIT: Based on your comment, you need to make your vhost look like this and then restart apache2.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
    <Directory /var/www/html>
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: @InspireShahin ok so did you do the rest of what I said?

Comment: here is the 000-default.conf file : <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Comment: @InspireShahin you need to allow .htaccess as I mentioned in the steps. See my edit.

Comment: This file not editable.. when I modify and save it show unable to save.. and when try to edit this " sudo  gedit url " it shown empty file..

Comment: try `sudo nano 000-default.conf` or do you have root access?

Comment: @InspireShahin what same message? and did you restart apache2 after editing the file?

Comment: Yes.. now showing this message every projects.. "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Ok so that means it works, now it's reading your .htaccess file sounds like. What is the content of your .htaccess file?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /new_notificamos/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Check your error_log file to see what the error message is that is causing the 500 internal server message

Comment: @jack Thank you for helping :) It was a simple problem. Htaccess file has some mistake now htacess file is : RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] It works for me.

Comment: @InspireShahin ok great. It will also help your reputation if you accept the answer since enabling htaccess in my steps allowed you to find the error.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure mod_rewrite module is loaded ? go to httpd.conf and search for -

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and make sure theres no # [hash tag] before

Comment: yah.. mod_rewrite is enable before another way.. but where is the httpd.conf file I can't find this file ?

Comment: well this depends on how you installed it ,it usually under /etc/apache2/conf but you can check if its enabled via [apache-get-modules](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-modules.php)

Comment: I have conf-available && conf-enabled folder in /etc/apache2/ root.. but I can't see the httpd.conf file anywhere. @Gal